# How can I change the width and height of parent div using js when we only have the id of the child

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the width and height of parent div using js when we only have the id of the child

```
<li>
  <span id="head-ing"><?=$row['subject']?></span>
  <script>
    /*what js to use*/
  </script>
</li>
```

The div comes from the Database. so i cannot modify that

Comment: I cannot use Inspect Element For that because the there is no ID of the div.

Comment: you want to change the `<li>` element ?

Comment: No just the parent div element

Comment: i know it in jquery u can easily access parent by `$("#child").parent().css({'height':'200px'})`

Answer (score 4):

Use `parentElement`:

```
document.getElementById("myLI").parentElement.style.width = "200px";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var child = document.getElementById("childId");
parent = child.parentNode;
parent.style.width= "100px";
parent.style.height= "100px";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12012651)